# ListView disable right tapped selection style

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, winrt-xaml, windows

I am trying to disable the right click functionality of my items inside a list view. I have tried handling the `RightTapped` event and setting the `e.handled` value to true. This has covered most of the list view's area however if I right click on the borders of the list view item, this selection style is still applied. I want the user to still be able to use the left click and apply the list selected styling. It is just the right click I want to disable.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
<ListView
        ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}"
        ItemClick="OnItemClicked"
        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
        SelectionMode="Multiple" 
        CanDragItems="True" 
        DragItemsStarting="OnDragItemsStarting"
        RightTapped="OnRightTapped"
        IsRightTapEnabled="False">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-1,3,-1,0" />
                <Setter Property="IsRightTapEnabled" Value="False"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Background="Transparent" RightTapped="OnRightTapped" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Width="300">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Grid.Column="0"  Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Width="55" Height="55" Margin="0,0,0,1"/>
                    <Image Margin="20,0,0,22" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="20" Height="20" Source="smallImage.png"/>

                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="30,0,0,0" Grid.Column="1">
                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="{Binding IsOnline, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToColorConverter}}" Style="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}" FontSize="20" Height="60"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Here is the code for the RightTapped handler:

```
    private void OnRightTapped(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Edit: When I click on the borders of an Item in the ListView the `OnRightTapped` event is not being fired. What could be swallowing this event?

Answer (score 0):

By playing with the background colors of the items inside my `ListView.ItemTemplate`, I found that my `TextBlock` was not covering the whole area of the row. By setting the `Column width` to the exact size of the `ListView` and setting the `RightTapped` event handler on this `Grid` I was able to cover all areas of right clicking. I still do not know why the `RightTapped` handler was not being fired for the `ListView` itself but this was a sufficient solution for what I needed.